# How to display all the elements on an arraylist to listview?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have this code of arraylist:

```
public List<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();
public List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
```

can you teach me how to display all the elements of the arraylist to a two column listview? also i want to display it through a new Intent.

```
    else if(v.getId()==R.id.btnFinal){
        Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, Finalize.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I want my list view to be diplayed on the Finalize class. please help me.

Comment: Search about **1**. Custom Adapter **2**. Transfer data between `Activities` **3**. Add your code you wrote here if there's something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get arraylist item to listview.This is used for a single column listview

```
 ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, column);
 listViewobj.setAdapter(aa);
```

IF you need to display it to a 2 column listview you can use a customized adapter 
 you can have an example [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/07/custom-list-view.html) and even the link contains how to know which item is clicked